# how to inject into a directive controller in ES6

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ecmascript-6

I have a directive that is written in es6. I need some services to be injected into this directive controller.
In es5, I would do something like:

```
function MyDirective() {

   function controller(commonService) {
       commonService.doSomething(this.type);
   };
   return {
        scope: {
           type: '='
        },
        restrict: 'E',
        controller: ['commonService', controller],
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        templateUrl: 'myTemplate.html',
        bindToController: true
   };
}

angular.module('myApp').directive('myDirective', ['commonService', MyDirective]);
```

That way, in ES5 everything used to works just fine. 
while in es6, I do:

```
class MyDirective {

       constructor(commonService) {

           this.scope = {
              type: '='
           };
           this.restrict = 'E';
           this.controllerAs = 'vm';
           this.templateUrl = 'myTemplate.html';
           this.bindToController: true;
       }

       controller() {
           commonService.doSomething(this.type);
       }
}

angular.module('myApp').directive('myDirective', [('commonService') => MyDirective(commonService)]);
```

The problem now is: I can no longer inject commonService into my controller.
I have tried to use

```
this.commonService = commonService;
```

in the constructor function, but unfortunatlly, I don't have access to "this" inside the controller for some odd reason. (Isn't that the whole point of having a class in the first place?)

How do I inject my commonService into the controller function, or alternatively, how do I gain access to "this" from the controller function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One option is to define the controller as a class.

## [The DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/r5por9bUsxSytgyiAFDk?p=preview)

```js
class MyDirective {

   constructor() {
       this.scope = {
          type: '@'
       };
       this.restrict = 'E';
       this.controller = 'myDirectiveCtrl',
       this.controllerAs = 'vm';
       this.template = `
           <fieldset>
              myDir type={{vm.type}}
              <br> Service {{vm.serviceType}}
           </fieldset>`;
       this.bindToController = true;
   }
}

class MyDirectiveCtrl {
    constructor(commonService) {
       this.commonService = commonService;
    }
    $onInit() {
       this.serviceType = this.commonService.doSomething(this.type);
    }
}
MyDirectiveCtrl.$inject = ['commonService'];

angular.module('myApp',[])
  .directive('myDirective', MyDirective)
  .controller("myDirectiveCtrl", MyDirectiveCtrl)
  .value("commonService", {
    doSomething: (type) => ("--"+type+"--")
  })
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <body ng-app="myApp">
    <h1>ES6 Directive Demo</h1>
    <my-directive type="IDK"></my-directive>
  </body>
```

Comment: Thanks! I do have a question though: Why would you need to explicitly assign the controller using the .controller if you have the this.controller = 'myDirectiveCtrl' assignment in the directive's body?

Comment: The `app.controller` statement stores the class in the controller cache of the [$controller service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$controller).  Using the string form of the `controller` property in the DDO specifies that the controller is to be injected from that cache.